# android-ndk Adding static libraries to the android.mk

Tags: android, makefile, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have three static libraries from a framework that I want to use in my project. These libraries are called `libtinySAK_armv7-a.a, libtinyNET_armv7-a.a and libtinyHTTP_armv7-a.a`. I have placed them in the same folder as the `Android.mk`and`Application.mk`.

My native code is dependent on them so I want to include them in my shared library.

From what I've read on stackoverflow and google'd I believe the android.mk is supposed to look something like this:

```
# TINYSAK
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tinySAK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtinySAK_armv7-a.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../doubango/tinySAK/src/

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


# TINYNET
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tinyNET
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtinyNET_armv7-a.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../doubango/tinyNET/src/

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


# TINYHTTP
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tinyHTTP
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtinyHTTP_armv7-a.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../doubango/tinyHTTP/include/

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)




LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libtest

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
../../test/stack.cpp \
../../test/main.cpp 

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../test/include/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../doubango/tinyHTTP/include/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../doubango/tinySAK/src/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../doubango/tinyNET/src/ 

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
tinySAK \
tinyNET \
tinyHTTP

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

The error I get upon compilation("ndk-build" from project dir) is

```
jni/Android.mk:tinySAK: LOCAL_SRC_FILES  points to a missing file
```

And I suppose the other 2 libraries also fail. Why cannot it find them?
Besides that, is there any other errors I've made in the makefile?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it.

I declared the "LOCAL_PATH" in the beginning of the make-file only. Otherwise it would look for the libs in the ndk-folders.

Comment: Where else should the LOCAL_PATH be declared

Answer (score 2):

Try `LOCAL_LDLIBS` instead of `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

Comment: this is what it says if I try that:"jni/Android.mk:tinySAK: The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt static library should only contain one item"